# grep regex how to remove single quote

Tags: regex, linux, grep, lvm

I'd like to get the quoted string from output of `lvscan` which is :

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/mysys/root' [297.46 GiB] inherit
```

What I've done is to use code below:

```
lvscan | grep -o "[^']\+\b'"
```

and what I got is :

```
/dev/mysys/root'
```

if I remove the very last single quote, I got three lines:

```
ACTIVE
/dev/mysys/root
[297.46 GiB] inherit
```

I also tried:

```
lvscan | grep -o "[@(^'\+.*)].*\>'"
lvscan | grep -o "[^']\+\>'"
```

What did I miss here?

Any comments would appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: The last line should be:   Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `-P` with `grep` you can use

`lvscan | grep -oP "(?<=')[^']+(?=')"`

Comment: can also use `grep -oP "'\K[^']+(?=')"`

Comment: Obviously, I'm not using Perl, and l'll check it out tomorrow, this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, vks, this line worked for me, I don't really care whether it's Perl Regex or not. An interesting question still remained though, is there a Basic  Regex solution for this?

Comment: @TaoWang basic regex can be used like `'([^']*)'` and then grab the group 1 but i have not used that with grep so m not sure

Comment: `lvscan | grep -Go "'.*'"` is the simplest answer I've tried for Basic Regex if ignoring single quotes pair.

Comment: The reason I wanna remove quotes is I'd like to print the output to a variable for later use. Insisting on keeping tried is for learning purpose, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` instead of `grep`:

```
lvscan | cut -f2 -d\'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this one worked as well. I think your suggestion would be easier. But vks' answer goes first, so I have to give my acceptance to vks.

Comment: Where have you seen such a rule? :-)